# Jquery Dynamically Replace Background Image

Tags: jquery, background-image

I'm trying to allow my users to dynamically change the background image of a specific DIV. They are doing this by uploading an image via a HTML form, once the image is uploaded I'm using JQuery to update the DIV's background.

I know this has been asked several times before and using an example I found on line I can replace the background image, however if the user wants to upload an new image and change it again then it fails to work.

It appears I can only change the image once, subsequent changes don't happen unless I refresh the page.

My DIV is using the following CSS

```
#background
{
    width:450px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url("images/background.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    #background-size: contain;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Onload the DIV has a default background image, the user uploads the image via the form and using the following JQuery I change the image to the new uploaded file.

```
$('#background').css("background-image", "url(" + filename + ")");
```

`filename` is the name of the file uploaded. This all works fine and the new image is shown.

If I upload another file, I can see the file has changed correctly in the upload folder, but the DIVs background doesn't change.

One thing I have noticed, after the first change is Chrome shows the CSS for the DIV with the following unticked.     `background-image: url(images/bacground.png);`, it also appears the DIV now has a style assigned to it with the name of the new file as the background.

How do I do this so they can change the background as often as they like ?

Thanks

Comment: check the image path where image is uploaded?

Comment: The image is uploaded correctly. It's just not updating on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't strange that Chrome set your `background-image` style unticked, because jquery set background-image as inline style of the element that always has a higher priority than styles from your css file.

Probably, you change old file with a new file, while they have the same name and Chrome don't update background, because he has old file with given name in its cache. You should load file with a new name and reset background-image.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense, I've tried applying a file with a different name and then the correct file, but that hasn't helped. Any ideas ?

Comment: Check do filename change in background-image property in element's style attribute after you've loaded a new file. If it does, check that each file you're trying to use have a unique url for browser, otherwise it doesn't reload it. The good way to do it is adding a server time to filename that user has loaded. Thus, you always get unique url for different files.

Comment: Thanks - I've started uploading the files and setting a tmp name based on the epoch timestamp, the images now update correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have done a simple example that will display background image on click on the button. In this example I have taken array of image url and set random image as a background image. This works fine for me. If this not work for you then let me know. Take the full url of the image you are uploading and set it to the container you want to set as a background image.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var filename = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/gateway/editorial/unrec/col-3/shipping-couple._CB509889188_.png";
//$('#background').css("background-image", "url(" + filename + ")");
document.getElementById("background").style.backgroundImage="url(" + filename + ")";
});

$("#changeBG").on("click", function () {
    var newarray = new Array();
    newarray[0] = "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41BcvUwPa0L._AC_UL260_SR200,260_.jpg";
    newarray[1] = "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31CvVeyn6OL._AC_UL260_SR200,260_.jpg";
    newarray[2] = "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51zMvKTKfzL._AC_UL260_SR200,260_.jpg";
    newarray[3] = "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31mxJooj4gL._AC_UL260_SR200,260_.jpg";
    newarray[4] = "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41brFl-yibL._AC_UL260_SR200,260_.jpg";
    var randomnumber = randomNumberFromRange(0, 4);
    document.getElementById("background").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + newarray[randomnumber] + ")";
});

function randomNumberFromRange(min, max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

```css
#background
{
  border:1px red solid;
    width:450px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url("images/background.png") 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    #background-size: contain;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background">

</div>
<input type="button" id="changeBG" value="Change Background Image">
```